# Stacking arrays with one different dimension using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Let's say I have 2 arrays:

```
a = np.array([[[1],[1]],[[2],[2]],[[3],[3]],[[4],[4]]])
b = np.array(["a", "b", "c", "d"]).reshape(4,1,1)
```

Then `a.shape = (4,2,1)` and `b.shape=(4,1,1)`. My desired output would look like this

```
c = np.array([
[
    np.array([[1],[1]]), "a"
],
[
    np.array([[2],[2]]), "b"
],
[
    np.array([[3],[3]]), "c"
],
[
    np.array([[4],[4]]), "d"
],
])
```

I tried `np.hstack` an `np.concatenate`, but that doesn't quite do what I want. I realize I can simply loop through `a` and `b` and create the array, I am simply wondering if there is a specific function, which would return array `c` or if loop is my best bet here.

Comment: the most near result i see is using concatenate over axis 1, but that's not exactly your expected result... can I ask why you need this? maybe there's other format that can meet your requirements..

Comment: Why are you trying to mix arrays and strings in an (object dtype) array?  Do you imagine you'll get some magical speed advantage from using arrays?  Or is such an array computationally better than a list?

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate in conjuntion with zip and a one-liner

```
a = np.array([[[1],[1]],[[2],[2]],[[3],[3]],[[4],[4]]])
b = np.array(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
c = np.array([[aa,bb] for aa,bb in zip(a,b)])
```

Comment: How is this different from OP iterating over their arrays with a for loop? I think they're looking for a specific numpy function to do the iteration, as that will be vectorized or at least written in C.

Comment: @LiquidSnake, the OP probably doesn't understand what he wants.  `c` is an object dtype array, so that "vectorized" magic doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can get is using `np.column_stack([a, b])`. However, this will include the string characters in the numpy array, instead of outside as you have.

```
>>> np.column_stack([a,b])
array([[['1'],
        ['1'],
        ['a']],

       [['2'],
        ['2'],
        ['b']],

       [['3'],
        ['3'],
        ['c']],

       [['4'],
        ['4'],
        ['d']]], dtype='<U11')
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove the unnecessary dimensions from `b`:

```
In [203]: b1 = b.ravel()
```

Second make a 4 element object dtype array from `a`:

```
In [204]: a1 = np.empty(4, object)
In [205]: a1[:] = list(a)
In [206]: a1
Out[206]: 
array([array([[1],
              [1]]), array([[2],
                            [2]]), array([[3],
                                          [3]]), array([[4],
                                                        [4]])],
      dtype=object)
```

Now we can `stack` them on a new 2nd axis to make a (4,2) array:

```
In [207]: np.stack((a1,b1), axis=1)
Out[207]: 
array([[array([[1],
               [1]]), 'a'],
       [array([[2],
               [2]]), 'b'],
       [array([[3],
               [3]]), 'c'],
       [array([[4],
               [4]]), 'd']], dtype=object)
```

The list comprehension is simpler, and probably faster:

```
In [209]: [[i,j.item()] for i,j in zip(a,b)]
Out[209]: 
[[array([[1],
         [1]]),
  'a'],
 [array([[2],
         [2]]),
  'b'],
 [array([[3],
         [3]]),
  'c'],
 [array([[4],
         [4]]),
  'd']]
```

Or make a structured array with 2 fields:

```
In [215]: c = np.zeros(4, dtype='O,U1')
In [216]: c
Out[216]: 
array([(0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, '')],
      dtype=[('f0', 'O'), ('f1', '<U1')])
In [218]: c['f0'] = list(a)
In [219]: c['f1'] = b.ravel()
In [220]: c
Out[220]: 
array([(array([[1],
              [1]]), 'a'), (array([[2],
                                  [2]]), 'b'), (array([[3],
                                                      [3]]), 'c'),
       (array([[4],
              [4]]), 'd')], dtype=[('f0', 'O'), ('f1', '<U1')])
```

or

```
In [221]: c = np.zeros(4, dtype=[('a',int,(2,1)),('b','U1')])
In [222]: c['a']=a    
In [224]: c['b']=b.ravel()
In [225]: c
Out[225]: 
array([([[1], [1]], 'a'), ([[2], [2]], 'b'), ([[3], [3]], 'c'),
       ([[4], [4]], 'd')], dtype=[('a', '<i8', (2, 1)), ('b', '<U1')])
```

The key to all these methods is understanding what you are trying to create.  You aren't making a "normal" multidimensional array.  You are trying to mix arrays and strings.

You can `concatenate` to make a (4,3,1) - and preserve ints by specifying the dtype.  This joins a (4,2,1) with a (4,1,1) on the middle dimension.  That's what concatenate (and the `stack` derivatives) does best.

```
In [263]: np.concatenate((a,b),axis=1, dtype=object)
Out[263]: 
array([[[1],
        [1],
        ['a']],

       [[2],
        [2],
        ['b']],

       [[3],
        [3],
        ['c']],

       [[4],
        [4],
        ['d']]], dtype=object)
```